# Convert matrix (CSV) into 3 column list in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, csv, matrix

I need to convert a matriz into a 3 column list. I have done that in Excel, but since my matrix is so big, I need to do it in python.

I have a something like this:

```
     A   B   C  ...
a    1   3   4  ...
b    4   0   6  ...
c    9   8   0  ...
```

And the output should be something like this in a CSV file (ignoring the 0s):

```
Source   Target    Weight
  a        A          1
  a        B          3
  a        C          4
  b        A          4
  b        C          6
  c        A          9
  c        B          8
```

Can somebody give me a hand, please?

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: You should probably consider using Pandas for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works perfect!!

```
In [335]: df.stack().reset_index().rename(columns={'level_0':'Source','level_1':'Target', 0:'Weight'})

Out[335]:

    Source Target  Weight
0      a      A       1
1      a      B       3
2      a      C       4
3      b      A       4
4      b      B       0
5      b      C       6
6      c      A       9
7      c      B       8
8      c      C       0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Pandas you may use special method [.to_csv()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) which can output csv to file. Also you can rename columns.